# Rails Version Resolving Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rvm

The root cause of my problem is that json 1.8.3 won't install. The original version of rails in my gem file was 4.1.14. I changed it to 4.1.16 and ran bundle update. json 1.8.6 was then installed locally.

However, when I deploy to Heroku, it still resolves the rails version to 4.1.16 and tries installing json 1.8.3 (which fails).

What can I do to resolve this issue and be able to successfully deploy my app?

Comment: after bundle install locally, are you pushing the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes I've committed and pushed changes to Gemfile.lock. Still having the same issue though

Answer (score 1):

The gem version should never resolve differently. That's the whole purpose of the `Gemfile.lock`.

Ensure that you have committed and pushed any changes to the `Gemfile.lock`.

If the file is not in source control (e.g. if you've added it to `.gitignore`?), then don't do that -- the file *should* be in source control.

Comment: Yes I've committed and pushed changes to Gemfile.lock. Still having the same issue though

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that the `Gemfile.lock` contains `json '1.8.6'`, and yet heroku is trying (and failing) to install `json '1.8.3'`? This should never happen. Can you please triple check that the file on heroku is correct?

Comment: ... And can you show the full error log of the failure? I don't know what you mean by "it fails"